# How to remove unwanted margins in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, margin

I am building a website in Twitter bootstrap. Using the grid system, I have 2 rows of 4 images which I have given the classes `col-xs-12`,`col-sm-6` and `col-md-3` respectively. In order to have a gap between the top row and bottom row I have given the top row an id and styled it in css as `img-responsive {margin-bottom: 30px}`. This is fine in desktop view, but on smaller devices it creates additional space once the images stack upon each other. Is there a way that this additional margin can be prevented using the media query function? Many thanks in advance, Jon.

[Here is the link to my website](http://www.jonhowlett.uk/about.html)

```
<div class="row" id="toprow">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <img src="images/about1_700x700.jpg" class="img-responsive" height="700" width="auto" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <img src="images/about1_700x700.jpg" class="img-responsive" height="700" width="auto" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <img src="images/about1_700x700.jpg" class="img-responsive" height="700" width="auto" alt=""/ id="image3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <img src="images/about1_700x700.jpg" class="img-responsive" height="700" width="auto" alt=""/ id="image4">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" id="bottomrow">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <img src="images/about1_700x700.jpg" class="img-responsive" height="700" width="auto" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <img src="images/about1_700x700.jpg" class="img-responsive" height="700" width="auto" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <img src="images/about1_700x700.jpg" class="img-responsive" height="700" width="auto" alt=""/ id="image7">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <img src="images/about1_700x700.jpg" class="img-responsive" height="700" width="auto" alt=""/ id="image8">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: In your code, while I was checking on tablet resolution I found #about #toprow is causing addition margin-bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Mobile First

While the other answers are perfectly fine, Bootstrap is a mobile-first framework. This probably shouldn't be it's own answer but I feel it needs a mention.

Adding to @Majid's code...

```
#toprow {
  margin-bottom: 30px;    
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #toprow {
    margin-bottom:0;    
  }
}
```

Doing this is fine. The margin will be set to 30px regardless of screen size and then removed for mobile screens. The mobile-first approach would be more like this...

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px) {
  #toprow {
    margin-bottom: 30px;    
  }
}
```

Notice how we're targeting `min-width` and we don't have to set the margin twice? We're adding it as we need it instead of overriding an existing rule. In a lot of situations this can save you from redundant code and make your projects a bit easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. Makes a lot more sense now. Seems every day I'm learning something new -so I'm grateful that there are people out there willing to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

ey, try somthing like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
            .col-xs-12{
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
            }
        }
```

adjust if necessary :)